# deployment topology constraint to ignore the anti affinity after first time

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, amazon-eks

am running a deployment in k8s that has 2 replicas and hpa depending on usage it can scale , am setting an antiaffinity for the pods to ensure HA but when the hpa scales it will need more nodes which is not my desire I want any replicas 2+ to be scheduled on any node not paying attention to the anti affinity , can I achieve this using topology constraints and maxskew ? if so can someone help me, I was not able to make it work

Answer (score -1):

There is no function that allows you to do what you say, but you can change your anti affinity rules from *requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution* to *preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution*.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-pod-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: security
            operator: In
            values:
            - S1
        topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: security
              operator: In
              values:
              - S2
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
  containers:
  - name: with-pod-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

> This example defines one Pod affinity rule and one Pod anti-affinity rule. The Pod affinity rule uses the "hard" requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution, while the anti-affinity rule uses the "soft" preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.

> The affinity rule says that the scheduler can only schedule a Pod onto a node if the node is in the same zone as one or more existing Pods with the label security=S1. More precisely, the scheduler must place the Pod on a node that has the topology.kubernetes.io/zone=V label, as long as there is at least one node in that zone that currently has one or more Pods with the Pod label security=S1.

> The anti-affinity rule says that the scheduler should try to avoid scheduling the Pod onto a node that is in the same zone as one or more Pods with the label security=S2. More precisely, the scheduler should try to avoid placing the Pod on a node that has the topology.kubernetes.io/zone=R label if there are other nodes in the same zone currently running Pods with the Security=S2 Pod label.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#an-example-of-a-pod-that-uses-pod-affinity

This way, every time you provision a new VM, the pods will be provisioned.

When the "even" node goes up, you simply have to schedule a restart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i was able to make it work using topologyspreadconstraint only